# What would be the fastest way to sort an array of random integers with an assumption that integers follow uniform distribution?

Tags: algorithm

Just like the tittle says. Integers are <0, 10^18>

Comment: Well, I don't know, [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)?

Answer (score 6):

[Flashsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashsort) is the sorting algorithm that exploits the data being in a known uniform distribution, `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

If the keys will always be integers, radix sort is more efficient than normal comparison-based sorts such as quicksort, scaling as O(kN), where N is the number of items, and k is the average key length in bits. Hence, this is linear in the number of integers you're sorting, and will win out over quicksort as N becomes large enough. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort for an explanation and an example C++ implementation.

Comment: Using radix sort is a very bad idea here. Radix sort works good only when the elements are very dense (`2^k < N`). However, in here, since `2^k ~= 2^60` - if `2^k < N` - it will probably mean the data won't fit in memory, and then you are going to need an external sort - which will be much faster then quick sort and radix sort.

Comment: Really? According to this benchmark (http://erik.gorset.no/2011/04/radix-sort-is-faster-than-quicksort.html), radix sort is pretty good even for small arrays.